# Flexslider only showing final slide on IE8-9

Tags: jquery, wordpress, flexslider

In IE8 & 9 - only the final slide is showing, although control nav buttons are working, it works fine in every other browser though.  Not sure if this is a CSS or jQuery problem.

Here is the site in question: http://bit.ly/SV8E0d

This is a WordPress site, and I'm initializing flexslider like this:

`jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: true,
        directionNav: true
      });
    });`

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Nice site! If your looking for general bugs too, the slide navigator does color two dots. instead of one.

Comment: Thanks very much Linuxos! - any idea on what the IE prob might be?

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know why but it seems IE didn't like `animation: "slide"`
Once I removed that it started working, albeit using the fade transition, but it's working!